# GitLab CI cannot find module error (when it is in node_modules)

Tags: javascript, gitlab, gitlab-ci, chai

I'm trying to run som client-side tests that connect to an endpoint on a server, which I'm using `chai.require("server.js")` to set up. This works on my local machine, but when I try and run this on GitLab CI, it fails and says it cannot find the modules inside the server.js file, even though they exist in node_modules (I printed these, and checked for the exact one it asked for). I also moved the require-s in server.js around, and it always fails on the first one / fails on all of them.

This is the relevant parts of my package.json file

```
{
"name": "client",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true
"dependencies": {
  "axios": "^0.19.1",
  "chai": "^4.2.0",
  "chai-http": "^4.3.0",
  "esm": "^3.2.25",
  "mocha": "^7.0.0",
  "mysql": "^2.17.1"
  "react-scripts": "3.3.0",
  "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
  "cors": "^2.8.5",
  "express": "^4.17.1",
  "install": "^0.13.0",
  "jest": "^24.9.0",
  "node": "^13.5.0",
  "npm": "^6.13.4",
  "require": "^2.4.20"
},
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start",
  "build": "react-scripts build",
  "test": "mocha --require esm \"src/**/*.test.js\"",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
"eslintConfig": {
  "extends": "react-app"
},
"browserslist": {
  "production": [
  ">0.2%",
  "not dead",
  "not op_mini all"
],
"development": [
  "last 1 chrome version",
  "last 1 firefox version",
  "last 1 safari version"
]
}, "devDependencies": {
  "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
  "jest": "^24.9.0"
}
}
```

And my .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: node:13

# Set up MySQL test-database
services:
  - mysql:5.5

# Configure test-database
variables:
  MYSQL_DATABASE: supertestdb
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret

# Install node libraries
before_script:
  - cd application/client
  - npm install

# Run JEST test

run_tests:
  stage: test
  script:
    - npm test
```

The error stacktrace from the CI Job:

```
client@0.1.0 test /builds/williaj/harmoni-team-7/application/client
62 > mocha --require esm "src/**/*.test.js"
63 /builds/williaj/harmoni-team-7/application/server/src/server.js:1
64 Error: Cannot find module 'express'
65 Require stack:
66 - /builds/williaj/harmoni-team-7/application/server/src/server.js
67 - /builds/williaj/harmoni-team- 
      7/application/client/src/test/storeTests/cookies.test.js
68 - /builds/williaj/harmoni-team- 
      7/application/client/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js
69 - /builds/williaj/harmoni-team- 
      7/application/client/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/one-and-dones.js
70 - /builds/williaj/harmoni-team- 
      7/application/client/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/options.js
71 - /builds/williaj/harmoni-team- 
      7/application/client/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/cli.js
72     at Object.<anonymous> (/builds/williaj/harmoni-team- 
      7/application/server/src/server.js:1)
73     at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
74     at Object.Module._extensions..js 
       (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1164:10)
75     at Object.<anonymous> (/builds/williaj/harmoni-team- 
      7/application/client/src/test/storeTests/cookies.test.js:12:13)
76     at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
77     at Object.Module._extensions..js 
      (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1164:10)
78     at /builds/williaj/harmoni-team- 
      7/application/client/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:308:36
79     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
80     at Mocha.loadFiles (/builds/williaj/harmoni-team- 
      7/application/client/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:305:14)
81     at Mocha.run (/builds/williaj/harmoni-team- 
      7/application/client/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:846:10)
82     at Object.exports.singleRun (/builds/williaj/harmoni-team- 
      7/application/client/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run-helpers.js:108:16)
83     at exports.runMocha (/builds/williaj/harmoni-team- 
      7/application/client/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run-helpers.js:143:13)
84     at Object.exports.handler (/builds/williaj/harmoni-team- 
      7/application/client/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run.js:305:3)
85     at Object.runCommand (/builds/williaj/harmoni-team- 
      7/application/client/node_modules/yargs/lib/command.js:242:26)
86     at Object.parseArgs [as _parseArgs] (/builds/williaj/harmoni-team- 
      7/application/client/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:1087:28)
87     at Object.parse (/builds/williaj/harmoni-team- 
      7/application/client/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:566:25)
88     at Object.exports.main (/builds/williaj/harmoni-team- 
      7/application/client/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/cli.js:68:6)
89     at Object.<anonymous> (/builds/williaj/harmoni-team- 
      7/application/client/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/cli.js:73:11)
90     at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
91     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
92   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
93   requireStack: [
94     '/builds/williaj/harmoni-team-7/application/server/src/server.js',
95     '/builds/williaj/harmoni-team- 
     7/application/client/src/test/storeTests/cookies.test.js',
96     '/builds/williaj/harmoni-team- 
     7/application/client/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js',
97     '/builds/williaj/harmoni-team- 
     7/application/client/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/one-and-dones.js',
98     '/builds/williaj/harmoni-team- 
     7/application/client/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/options.js',
99     '/builds/williaj/harmoni-team- 
     7/application/client/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/cli.js'
100   ]
101 }
102 npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

And to re-iterate, it's the `chai.require('server.js')` that then again run the imports that crash the CI, and this runs on my machine. Thankful for any answers.

Comment: Can you add the error stacktrace ?

Comment: @TristanDeoliveira I did now.

Comment: For anyone looking for an answer here, I never found one. Just to let you know.

Answer (score 4):

Happened something similar to me with pipeline cache, in my case what solved the problem appears to be "Clear Runner caches" through the Gitlab UI.

[Read this documentation in order to understand about what button i'm talking about](http://www.obsis.unb.br/gitlab/help/ci/caching/index.md#clearing-the-cache)

Answer (score 2):

If this could be relevant, I had a similar issue on my pipeline.
I moved the **cache** config from a job to the global, leading to this conf :

```yaml
    image: weboaks/node-karma-protractor-chrome
    
    cache:
        paths:
        - node_modules/
    
    stages:
      - test
      - release
      - postrelease
      - deploy
      - e2e
```

I no longer had the issue when running npm command from multiple jobs.

Comment: I no longer have access to this project and cannot test this, as it was for school, but I'll leave the question up as your answer might help others.